# Django simpleJWT error "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

i'm trying to log into an account that isn't superuser and getting an error from rest_framework

```
"detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
```

using a custom user model

models.py :

```
lass UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user
    

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin ):
    
    first_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    User_Roles = models.ForeignKey(User_Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

  
    objects = BaseUserManager()
```

i checked that the passwords are being hashed in the db but does not seem to be the case

serializers.py :

```
class RegisterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta():
        model = CustomUser
        fields =    ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'password2']
        

    def save(self):
        user = CustomUser(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            username=self.validated_data['username'],
            first_name=self.validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=self.validated_data['last_name'],
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password'],
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2'],

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must Match'})
        user.set_password(str(password))
        user.save()
        return user
```

i had error where the password type was a tuple rather than a string or byte, and

`user.set_password(str(password))` 
seems to have fixed the issue that i wasn't able to figure out,

the user is created and stored with a hashed password, but can't log in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Remove the trailing commas in the following lines

```py
password = self.validated_data['password'],
password2 = self.validated_data['password2'],
```

The result should be

```py
password = self.validated_data['password']
password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
```

## Explanation

By adding a comma, you've made it becomes a tuple which will make the error occur since the password field is a string type, not a tuple.

> `user.set_password(str(password))` seems to have fixed the issue that i wasn't able to figure out,

This seems to fix the issue, however, it actually will introduce another issue which is password value will be set as `(PASSWORD,)` before being encrupted via `set_password()` method.